# tf.gfile.FastGFile(imagePath, 'rb').read()

Tags: python, tensorflow

i try to inception_v3 example.
I use the under code, but I want to put the image itself, not the image path. Is there a way?

```
def run_inference_on_image():
    answer = None

    if not tf.gfile.Exists(imagePath):
        tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', imagePath)
        return answer

    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(imagePath, 'rb').read()

    create_graph()

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                           {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
        predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

        top_k = predictions.argsort()[-2:][::-1]  
        f = open(labelsFullPath, 'rb')
        lines = f.readlines()
        labels = [str(w).replace("\n", "") for w in lines]
        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = labels[node_id]
            score = predictions[node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))

        answer = labels[top_k[0]]
    return answer
```

An image is an image that I want to classify as a learned PB file.

Comment: What do you mean by "image itself"?

Comment: You can modify the contents to check the contents of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`image_data` is the actual image bytes in your code. And they are being used inside sess.run() function. Below line of code returns the image bytes as a string.

> tf.gfile.FastGFile(imagePath, 'rb').read()

So, all you have to do is pass a `string of image bytes` to `sess.run()` which can be done in several ways :-

```
# method 1
import cv2
img_str = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tostring()

# method 2
from scipy.ndimage import imread
imgbytes = imread(img_path)
img_str = imgbytes.tostring()
```

Check what works for you.